# Как выбрать следующий элемент после $(this)

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Вот код который есть:

```
<div class="input">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <div class="process"></div>
</div>

$('input').keypress(function(){
     $(this).next('.process').addClass('loading');
});
```

Задумка здесь такова, что при нажатии на клавиши, появляется значок загрузки, но это в принципе не важно. Мне нужно узнать как выбрать ('.process') если между INPUT  и ('.process') стоит еще какой нибудь тег.

```
<div class="input">
   <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
   <div class="error"></div>
   <div class="process"></div>
</div>
```

Код приведенный, ниже уже не сработает.

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
         $(this).next('.process').addClass('loading');
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
     $(this).siblings('.process').addClass('loading');
});
```

[tree-traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)